# How to reference a spring bean explicitly in a SpEL expression

Tags: spring-webflow, spring-bean

Hi I have a spring bean named "connection" - how can I reference that explicitly in a SpEL expression from webflow - by explicitly I mean I don't want SpEL to try and find any other variables named "connection" which may exist in webflow scope - this is what I'm currently doing:

```
<action-state id="initialise-connection">
    <evaluate result="flowScope.initialisedConnection" expression="connection"/>
```

I've read about prefixing with "@" to only target beans - what is the right practice and how do I do it?

Comment: give this a try #{connection}

Answer (score 0):

The `evaluate` tag used to invoke a bean method or an `execute()` method inside subclass of [`Action`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.0.M1/api/org/springframework/webflow/execution/Action.html) class

For example if you define your own action, it should be initialized as `@Component` or defined as `bean` in your `XML` configuration file

```
@Component
public class MyAction {
   public Connection doSomething(RequestContext context){
    ...
   }
}
```

And in your flow definition `XML` file, you would simply call it like this

```
<evaluate result="flowScope.initialisedConnection" expression="myAction.doSomething( flowRequestContext)"/>
```

But if you defined a subclass of [`Action`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.0.M1/api/org/springframework/webflow/execution/Action.html) class, it will be like this

```
@Component
public class MyAction implements Action {

   @Override
   public Event execute(RequestContext context) {
     ...
   }
}
```

And in your flow definition `XML` file, you would call it like this

```
<evaluate result="flowScope.initialisedConnection" expression="myAction"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I used to call a static method in a Class of mine. Please try this.

```
<action-state id="initialise-connection">
    <evaluate result="flowScope.initialisedConnection" expression="@com.app.connection.method()"/>
</acton>
```